# how to Creating JSON each input value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to print some data in JSON format for another apps use.
How I should construct the Javascript object to create the JSON format dynamically.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frstname" data-conv="json">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" data-conv="json">
        <select name="gender" class="form-control" data-conv="json">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" data-conv="json">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" data-conv="json">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn-action" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have try with following Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-action').on('click', function(){

        var jsonObj = [];
        $("input[data-conv=json]").each(function() {
            var firstname = $(input[name=frstname]).val();
            var lastname  = $(input[name=lastname]).val();
            var gender    = $(input[name=gender]).val();
            var dob       = $(input[name=dob]).val();
            var email     = $(input[name=email]).val();

            item = {}
            item ['firstname']  = firstname;
            item ['lastname']   = lastname;
            item ['gender']     = gender;
            item ['dob']        = dob;
            item ["email"]      = email;

            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        console.log(jsonString);
    });
});
```

I am getting ERROR:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting ERROR:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

you need to wrap each input in your selector with `'` or `"`:

```
var firstname = $('input[name=frstname]').val();
var lastname  = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
var gender    = $('input[name=gender]').val();
var dob       = $('input[name=dob]').val();
var email     = $('input[name=email]').val();
```

the same what you did here:

```
$("input[data-conv=json]").each(function() {
```

Though if you have 1 forum with these controls you dont need the each:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-action').on('click', function(){

        var jsonObj = [];

        var firstname = $('input[name=frstname]').val();
        var lastname  = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
        var gender    = $('input[name=gender]').val();
        var dob       = $('input[name=dob]').val();
        var email     = $('input[name=email]').val();

        item = {}
        item ['firstname']  = firstname;
        item ['lastname']   = lastname;
        item ['gender']     = gender;
        item ['dob']        = dob;
        item ["email"]      = email;

        jsonObj.push(item);

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        console.log(jsonString);
    });
});
```

but if you have multiples you need to give the group arround the elements a class:-

```
<div class="form-group inputs-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frstname" data-conv="json">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" data-conv="json">
```

then `each` over that using `find`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-action').on('click', function(){

        var jsonObj = [];
        $(".inputs-group").each(function() {
            var firstname = $(this).find('input[name=frstname]').val();
            var lastname  = $(this).find('input[name=lastname]').val();
            var gender    = $(this).find('input[name=gender]').val();
            var dob       = $(this).find('input[name=dob]').val();
            var email     = $(this).find('input[name=email]').val();

            item = {}
            item ['firstname']  = firstname;
            item ['lastname']   = lastname;
            item ['gender']     = gender;
            item ['dob']        = dob;
            item ["email"]      = email;

            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        console.log(jsonString);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have edit code as you advice like $('input[name=frstname]').val(); but it print 4 times, [{"firstname":"","lastname":"","dob":"","email":""},{"firstname":"","lastname":"","dob":"","email":""},{"firstname":"","lastname":"","dob":"","email":""},{"firstname":"","lastname":"","dob":"","email":""}] How to fix it?